# pprofile.Profile().print_stats() display in IPython

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, profile

I tried pprofile to profile Python code line by line.

```
import pprofile
profiler = pprofile.Profile()
```

I printed the statistics to the Ipython console using

```
profiler.print_stats()
```

This works, however, the plotted table has a lot of rows and the upper part is cut away by IPython. Since those are the data I'm interested in I need to see those.
Is there any basic IPython setting that enlarges the number of rows to display?
Obviously the profiler.print_stats() command can't be modified to exclude unneeded data from being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

There are other methods you could call instead of print_stats(), like

> profiler.dump_stats(filename)

which dumps the same output to filename.
Or if you know the name of the file you are insterested in, you could call the method underlying dump_* methods:

> profiler.annotate(sys.stdout, source_filename)

which dumps an annotated version of just given filename.

See the module/class documentation for more information:

> help(pprofile)